# how to display user defined location

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

- I am new to swift.
- please guide me how to display `location` on map when user enter any place in textfield.
- by using this textfield string how to display this location on `map`.
  This is my code

  ```
  import UIKit
  import CoreLocation
  import MapKit
  class DetailViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

  var manager:CLLocationManager!
  var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []


  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
  {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  //Setup our Location Manager
      manager = CLLocationManager()
      manager.delegate = self
      manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
      manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      manager.startUpdatingLocation()
      //Setup our Map View
      theMap.delegate = self
      theMap.mapType = MKMapType.Satellite
      theMap.showsUserLocation = true

  }
  func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
      theLabel.text = "\(locations[0])"
      myLocations.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)

      let spanX = 0.007
      let spanY = 0.007
      var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
      theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)
      if (myLocations.count > 1){
          var sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
          var destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2
          let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
          let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
          var a = [c1, c2]
          var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
          theMap.addOverlay(polyline)
      }
  }
  ```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that's how your view controller is designed.When user click on the "Find location" button we will convert the text entered by user into address and place an annotation on the map.
[image]

```
@IBOutlet var userinput: UITextField!
@IBAction func findlocation(sender: AnyObject) {
if(userinput.text == "")
 {
 //location cannot be empty.Show an alert to notify user
 }
 else
 {
  var address:String = userinput.text as String // 1 Infinite Loop, CA, USA
 var geocoder = CLGeocoder()
 geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
 if let placemark = placemarks?[0] as? CLPlacemark {
       self.mapView.addAnnotation(MKPlacemark(placemark: placemark))
 }
 })
 }
 }
```